# Substring filtering in Altair / using "params"

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I am using Altair and would like to filter data using a substring search. [Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9p3OgENCCvCCgKAtphQg6IOSA0KATgGsdABwglx3TFEh0SSVCAAeqwgE8L25CABHUgUiOGViNG1ueEwAGz1-NzQFWJBuSjAUv1A6CCMSFABtLhYAXVluL08fP0Dg0PC4SLSQGPidL2TU9MzY7N08hQLkQoBGTlG2coqQCxNNSiLQdS0dABlMQkJMYxau0lqAQRaAIxIE0BILUnF-SjjMMFsQCAtiaEWRkGPuACEWgDCLQAIi0AKItABiIGmpW4hGMIUoMAgxg0S1acFi212-nOmDcEBgAApFIRSBoAHQkFGcAAEGy2OwAlAA+AC0o30cN0SgU90InxyGKSKRQ4xAnTFyAA7NwaRAdIcANy-ZXA5UQuSgUWpZAAJkqXRQhpACqVyoBmuV0O17mNyAkRulAE55bBFf4VWrQdJpkA) is an example of doing it in vega-lite. Here is the code:

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300}},
  "data": {"name": "d"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "xval", "scale":{"domain": [0,4]}},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "yval", "scale":{"domain": [1,10]}}
  },
  "params": [{"name": "Letter", "value": "A", 
    "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]}
  }],
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "indexof(datum.info, Letter)>-1"}
  ],
  "datasets": {
    "d": [
      {"xval": 1, "yval": 7, "info": "A;B;D;E"},
      {"xval": 2, "yval": 2, "info": "A;C;E;F"},
      {"xval": 3, "yval": 9, "info": "A;B;D"}
    ]
  }
}
```

This allows me to filter out rows that contain "A", "B", "C" etc. in the info column, but it relies on `"params"` which is [not available](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2442) in Altair yet - is there any other way of achieving this kind of "substring" filtering in Altair as of now? This is meant to be a minimal example, but I have a large number of "options" (many gene names) in my actual use case, so adding a column for each to the original data wouldn't be feasible.

Trying to do this in Altair because it is for an executable research article which I believe allows Altair but not vega-lite.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: realized that indexing like `infoSel.info[0]` gives the string of the selection from the dropdown. This still worked with `infoSel.info` (with no index) but that was just lucky - in expressions like this doing `infoSel.info[0]` is more correct.

Got it! This is possible with an expression in `transform_filter`, which I had previously tried but done incorrectly (I was using the name of the dropdown, not the name of the select object):

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'xval': [1, 2, 3], 
                  'yval': [7, 2, 9], 
                  'info': ['A;B;D;E', 'A;C;E;F', 'B;D']})
info_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], name='Letter')
info_sel = alt.selection_single(name='infoSel', fields=['info'], bind=info_dropdown, init={'info': 'A'}) 
alt.Chart(d).mark_circle().encode(
    x='xval', y='yval'
    ).add_selection(info_sel).transform_filter('indexof(datum.info, infoSel.info[0])>-1')
```